# How to use a slider in plotly to turn visibility of 3D data points on/off?

Tags: python, plotly, slider, interactive

I am using plotly to plot data points in 3D from with a code that looks something like that:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame
df_ids_plot = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'y': [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    'z': [3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    'weight': [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]  
})

# Create initial figure
fig = go.Figure()

# Add scatter plot
scatter = fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(
    x=df_ids_plot['x'],
    y=df_ids_plot['y'],
    z=df_ids_plot['z'],
    mode='markers',
))

fig.show()
```

What I want to do next is to implement a slider and use this slider to throw away data points from the plot (turn their visibility off) when the value of the slider that I set gets larger than the `weight` of the data points. E.g. when I set the slider to 6 I want all data points with `weight`<6 to become invisible in the plot. I looked through the limited slider documentation [here](https://plotly.com/python/sliders/) and [here](https://plotly.com/python/range-slider/), but I didn't find how to do this.

Optionally, it would be nice if I could use a range slider and restrict with it the min and max value of data points simultaneously, e.g. set the range slider to min_value=4, max_value=6 and then only data points get displayed who's weight is within the range 4<weight<6. Thx for advice how to do this!